# Reading static var from protocol extension instance method

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Let's say we have a Swift protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    static var someString: String { get }
}
```

Is there a way to access `someString` from an extension instance method, like so?

```
extension SomeProtocol {
    public func doSomething() -> String {
        return "I'm a \(someString)"
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error:

> Static member 'someString' cannot be used on instance of type 'Self'

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to refer to `someString` with `Self` (*note the uppercase `S`*):

```
extension SomeProtocol {
    public func doSomething() -> String {
        return "I'm a \(Self.someString)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution is not specific to protocols or protocol extensions. The use of `Self.someStatic` works when accessing a static member from an instance member of the same class/struct/enum.